# Need to remove www from $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] how?

Tags: php

I need to remove www from the string given by `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']`

How can I do that in PHP?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
$server_name = str_replace("www.", "", $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']);
```

That should do the trick...

Comment: This will remove "www." from anywhere in the Host, rather than only at the start. If someone's domain was "my-www.com" they would get unexpected results.

Answer (score 8):

```
if (substr($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'], 0, 4) == 'www.') {
    $domain = substr($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'], 4);
} else {
    $domain = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Client requested site name "www.example.com"

```
// explode the string at the '.' and inserts into an array 
$pieces = explode(".", $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']); 
// $pieces array is now:
// now $pieces[0] contains "www"
// now $pieces[1] contains "example"
// now $pieces[2] contains "com"
// Put the domain name back together using concatenation operator ('.')
$DomainNameWithoutHostPortion =  $pieces[1].'.'.$pieces[2];
// now $DomainNameWithoutHostPortion contains "example.com"
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `str_replace`, you could use `ltrim`:

```
$sender_domain = $_SERVER[HTTP_HOST];
$sender_domain = ltrim($sender_domain, 'www.');
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you want this:

```
$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] = str_replace('www.', '',$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']);
```

Answer (score -1):

Here

```
$host = str_replace('www.', null, $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'])
```

You can also

```
 $ht = "http://";
 $host = str_replace('www.',$ht, $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'])
```